# SQLServer Table Linked in MS Access Database

Tags: database, ms-access

I have one table in SQL Server which is based in London. That table is linked n MS access Database which is in Mumbai.

If i try to query the Linked Table i am getting error saying ODBC call Failed.
ODBC SQL Server Time Out.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: How much bandwidth do you have between the sites?

Answer (score 0):

Access tables perform very poorly on anything less than a local network or at speeds like 100 mbps on the WAN connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tony...Is there anything to do with QUERY TIMEOUT SETTINGs in SQL / Access / DSN ?

Comment: Er, the question seems to imply that the tables are in SQL Server, not Jet/ACE.

Answer (score 0):

In the query design view, **Right Click** on the query's "Canvas" area and select **Properties** form the drop-down list.

Change the **ODBC Time-Out** value from the default 60 to 0.